# How to remove \thispagestyle{empty} after appendixpage?

Tags: appendix

Using the `appendix` package, I would like to remove `\thispagestyle{empty}` so that the page after `\appendixpage` contains numbering and the general style of the rest of document. I succesfully managed to remove `\appendixpage` after `\part` but did not manage to do the same for the `appendix`.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to patch `\@chap@pppage`:

```latex
\usepackage[page]{appendix}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chap@pppage}
  {\thispagestyle{empty}}
  {}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text in the example

\usepackage[page]{appendix}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chap@pppage}
  {\thispagestyle{empty}}
  {}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\begin{appendices}
  \blinddocument
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, @esdd. It worked as intended!